# How to animate a QSplitter?

Tags: c++, qt

Given the **following** example built-in Qt Designer:

[image]

The GUI is started with the space occupied by `frame` hidden:

```
    QList<int> list = { 0, 400 };
    ui.splitter->setSizes(list);
    ui.frame->setWindowOpacity(0);
```

How can I animate the `frame` while bringing her occupied space back?

I tried animating it as:

---

```
// splitteranimation.h

void SplitterAnimation(QWidget* widget)
{
    int ani_speed = 1000;

    QPropertyAnimation* geo_ani = new QPropertyAnimation(widget, "geometry");
    geo_ani->setDuration(ani_speed);
    geo_ani->setStartValue(widget->rect());

    QRect end = QRect(widget->rect().x(), widget->rect().y(), widget->rect().width() + 200, widget->rect().height());
    geo_ani->setEndValue(end);



    QGraphicsOpacityEffect *eff = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect();
    widget->setGraphicsEffect(eff);
    QPropertyAnimation *op_eff = new QPropertyAnimation(eff, "opacity");
    op_eff->setDuration(ani_speed);
    op_eff->setStartValue(0);
    op_eff->setEndValue(1);



    auto animgroup = new QParallelAnimationGroup;
    animgroup->addAnimation(geo_ani);
    animgroup->addAnimation(op_eff);
    animgroup->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

---

```
#include "splitteranimation.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QList<int> list = { 0, 400 };
    ui.splitter->setSizes(list);
    ui.frame->setWindowOpacity(0);

    QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F2), this);
    connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, [=]
    {
        qDebug() << "shortcut!";
        SplitterAnimation(ui.frame);

    });

    shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F3), this);
    connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, [this]
    {
        qDebug() << "shortcut!";
        SplitterAnimation(ui.splitter);
    });
}
```

When I call the geometry animation in the `frame` (F2), the `frame` get resized but the space occupied by it continue 'hidden', the splitter areas didn't get resized:

[image]

When i call the animation directly in the splitter (F3), the frame didn't get resized/ visible.

Answer (score 0):

Why the size is not adjusted is easy to answer.
You use the `geometry` property (in your animation). But since you use layouts
this undesirable behavior occurs.

To animate the splitter you can subclass `QSplitter':

`splitter.h`

```
#ifndef SPLITTER_H
#define SPLITTER_H

#include <QSplitter>

class Splitter : public QSplitter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Splitter(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QSplitter( parent)
    {
    }
public slots:
    void splitterAnimation(QVariant variant)
    {
        qDebug() << variant.toInt();
        moveSplitter(variant.toInt(), 1);
    }
};

#endif // SPLITTER_H
```

The splitter has the method `moveSplitter(int, int)`. the first argument is the `pos`,then the `index`.
I've shortened this with QVariantAnimation. But if you have properties
put in the splitter class QPropertyAnimation or other (there are many possibilities) then you do that.
So in general you shouldn't use `geometry` properties in layouts.

here is the simple animation (only fragments) in the constructor:

`Edit`
to save the current position of the splitter, you can use the `Signal` splitterMoved(int, int) from the QSplitter.

```
void Widget::on_splitter_splitterMoved(int pos, int index)
{
    posStep = pos;
    if(f2Pressed)
    {
        posStep = posStep;
        f2Pressed = false;
    }
    if(f3Pressed)
    {
        posStep = posStep;
        f3Pressed = false;
    }
}
```

`widget.h`

```
.....
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QVariantAnimation *splitterAnimation;
    int posStep;
    bool f2Pressed;
    bool f3Pressed;
.....
```

`widget.cpp`

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    
    QList<int> lst = {0,400};
    ui->splitter->setSizes(lst);

    posStep = 0;
    splitterAnimation = new QVariantAnimation();
    splitterAnimation->setDuration(1000);
    splitterAnimation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InSine);
    connect(splitterAnimation, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged,
            ui->splitter, &Splitter::splitterAnimation);

    QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F2), this);
    connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, [=]()
            {
                f2Pressed = true;
                splitterAnimation->setStartValue(posStep);
                splitterAnimation->setEndValue(400);
                ui->label->setText("F2 Pressed");
                splitterAnimation->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Forward);
                splitterAnimation->start();

            });
    QShortcut *shortcut2 = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F3), this);
    connect(shortcut2, &QShortcut::activated, [=]()
            {
                f3Pressed = true;
                splitterAnimation->setStartValue(0);
                splitterAnimation->setEndValue(posStep);
                ui->label->setText("F3 Pressed");
                splitterAnimation->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
                splitterAnimation->start();
            });
}
```

or with `QPropertyAnimation` : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXJdf.png

[image]

Comment: I'm getting these errors: https://i.imgur.com/IxF8HBz.png

Comment: it looks like you passed something wrong in the subclass. with the signal and slot concept, the arguments must be the same. do you have it in the splitter class for `SLOT` like this: `moveSplitter(variant.toInt(), 1);` ? -> and `void splitterAnimation(QVariant variant)`

Comment: if you want to use `QPropertyAnimation` here is another example https://i.imgur.com/EOY26uQ.png
If my answer was helpful to you, you can mark it as such. if someone else has exactly the same problem, he can look here. that sometimes helps with the search

Comment: Thank you! ill try it, could you share the code on a website like https://pastebin.com/? so it could be easier to me read it

Comment: here is the code. you need to edit it for your project. https://pastebin.com/4bf1CV5n